# Fetching League of Legends match data by Incrementing matchID by 1: seemingly spaghetti code works but organized code doesn't?

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, http-status-code-404, riot-games-api

This is sphagetti code I wrote to brute-force match ID's by increments of 1 to call various endpoints from Riot's server. It has since worked for 12 hours and has written 14,050 lines without errors (before manual termination)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from csv import writer
import time
fixed_api_key= '(insert API key from Riot here)' 

matchnum=5995866984

j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
r = requests.get(matchdata)#call match data
print (r.status_code)
info_clmns= ['Creation Time','gameDuration','gameEndTimestamp','GameEnd','gameId','gameMode','gameStartTimestamp','GameStart', 'gameType','gameVersion','platformId','queueId']
info_df= pd.DataFrame(columns=info_clmns)
#info_df.to_csv("(csv name).csv", index=False, encoding= 'cp949') #making headings on csv
while matchnum<(5995866984+6000):
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(str(matchnum)+' SUCCESS, entrynumber #'+ str(info_df.shape[0]))
        info= r.json()['info']
        i0= info['gameCreation']
        i0a= pd.to_datetime(i0, unit='ms')
        i1= info['gameDuration'] 
        i2= info['gameEndTimestamp'] 
        i2a= pd.to_datetime(i2, unit='ms')
        i3= info['gameId']
        i4= info['gameMode']
        i5= info['gameStartTimestamp']
        i5a= pd.to_datetime(i5, unit='ms')
        i6= info['gameType']
        i7= info['gameVersion']
        i8= info['platformId'] 
        i9= info['queueId']
        infodata= [[i0a,i1,i2,i2a,i3, i4,i5,i5a,i6,i7,i8,i9]]
        new= pd.DataFrame(infodata, columns=info_clmns)
        info_df= pd.concat([info_df,new])
                                #writing to csv
        newlist= list(new.loc[0])
        with open ('(csv name).csv', 'a', newline="") as f_object:
            writer_object = writer(f_object)
            writer_object.writerow(newlist)
            f_object.close()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
        matchnum= matchnum+1
        j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
        matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
        r = requests.get(matchdata)

    elif r.status_code == 429:
            print('api cost full : infinite loop start')
            print('loop location : ',matchnum)
            start_time = time.time()

            while True: # loop until 429 error no longer appears
                if r.status_code == 429:

                    print('try 10 second wait time')
                    time.sleep(10)

                    r = requests.get(matchdata)
                    print(r.status_code)
                elif r.status_code == 404:
                    print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                    print('recovery api cost')
                    break

                elif r.status_code == 200: #escape loop when response code= 200
                    print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                    print('recovery api cost')
                    break
                else:
                    print(str(r.status_code)+'. trying again after 5 sec')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    r.requests.get(matchdata)
                    break
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        
        print ('404, trying '+str(matchnum+1))
        matchnum= matchnum+1
        j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
        matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
        r = requests.get(matchdata)
        continue

info_df
```

This second snippet is code I wrote to be more 'modular', referencing existing code written by someone fetching similar data from the Riot API. It pushes the dataframe creation and csv writing to the end and puts various exceptions for error codes in front. This runs up to entry #49 and generates an output like below.

```
#alternate code
import pandas as pd
import requests
from csv import writer
import time
info_clmns= ['Creation Time','gameDuration','gameEndTimestamp','GameEnd','gameId','gameMode','gameStartTimestamp','GameStart', 'gameType','gameVersion','platformId','queueId']
info_df= pd.DataFrame(columns=info_clmns)
info_df.to_csv("(csv name).csv", index=False, encoding= 'cp949') #making headings on csv
api_key= '(insert API key from Riot here' 

matchnum=5995866984

j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + api_key
r = requests.get(matchdata)#call match data


while matchnum<(5995866984+9000):
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        pass

    elif r.status_code == 429:
        print('api cost full : infinite loop start')
        print('loop location : ',matchnum)
        start_time = time.time()

        while True: # loop until 429 error no longer appears
            if r.status_code == 429:

                print('try 10 second wait time')
                time.sleep(10)

                r = requests.get(matchdata)
                print(r.status_code)

            elif r.status_code == 200: #escape loop when response= 200
                print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                print('recovery api cost')
                break
    elif r.status_code == 503: # exception for "service unavailable error"
        print('service available error')
        start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            if r.status_code == 503 or r.status_code == 429:

                print('try 10 second wait time')
                time.sleep(10)

                r = requests.get(matchdata)
                print(r.status_code)
            elif r.status_code == 404:
                        print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                        print('recovery api cost')
                        break

            elif r.status_code == 200: # same as above, escape loop when response= 200
                print('total error wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                print('recovery api cost')
                break
        
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        
        while True:
            if r.status_code == 429:
                print('api cost full : infinite loop start')
                print('loop location : ',matchnum)
                start_time = time.time()

                while True: 
                        if r.status_code == 429 or r.status_code== 503:

                            print('try 10 second wait time')
                            time.sleep(10)

                            r = requests.get(matchdata)
                            print(r.status_code)
                        elif r.status_code == 404:
                            print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                            print('recovery api cost')
                            break

                        elif r.status_code == 200: 
                            print('total wait time : ', time.time() - start_time)
                            print('recovery api cost')
                            break
            elif r.status_code== 404:
                print('404 on '+str(matchnum))
                matchnum= matchnum+1
                j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
                matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + api_key
                r = requests.get(matchdata)
                
            
            elif r.status_code== 200:
                break
    else:
        print (r.status_code)
        print('misc error. try waiting 10 s')
        time.sleep(10)
        r=requests.get(matchdata)

    print(str(matchnum)+' SUCCESS, entrynumber #'+ str(info_df.shape[0]))
    info= r.json()['info']
    i0= info['gameCreation']
    i0a= pd.to_datetime(i0, unit='ms')
    i1= info['gameDuration'] 
    i2= info['gameEndTimestamp'] 
    i2a= pd.to_datetime(i2, unit='ms')
    i3= info['gameId']
    i4= info['gameMode']
    i5= info['gameStartTimestamp']
    i5a= pd.to_datetime(i5, unit='ms')
    i6= info['gameType']
    i7= info['gameVersion']
    i8= info['platformId'] 
    i9= info['queueId']
    infodata= [[i0a,i1,i2,i2a,i3, i4,i5,i5a,i6,i7,i8,i9]]
    new= pd.DataFrame(infodata, columns=info_clmns)
    info_df= pd.concat([info_df,new])
                            #writing to csv
    newlist= list(new.loc[0])
    with open ('(csv name).csv', 'a', newline="") as f_object:
        writer_object = writer(f_object)
        writer_object.writerow(newlist)
        f_object.close()
    time.sleep(0.9)

    matchnum= matchnum+1
    j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
    matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + api_key
    r = requests.get(matchdata)
info_df #display time info
```

output looks like:

```
5995866985 SUCCESS, entrynumber #0
404 on 5995866986
5995866987 SUCCESS, entrynumber #1
404 on 5995866988
404 on 5995866989
5995866990 SUCCESS, entrynumber #2
5995866991 SUCCESS, entrynumber #3
404 on 5995866992
5995866993 SUCCESS, entrynumber #4
5995866994 SUCCESS, entrynumber #5
5995866995 SUCCESS, entrynumber #6
404 on 5995866996
404 on 5995866997
5995866998 SUCCESS, entrynumber #7
5995866999 SUCCESS, entrynumber #8
404 on 5995867000
404 on 5995867001
404 on 5995867002
404 on 5995867003
5995867004 SUCCESS, entrynumber #9
404 on 5995867005
5995867006 SUCCESS, entrynumber #10
404 on 5995867007
404 on 5995867008
404 on 5995867009
5995867010 SUCCESS, entrynumber #11
404 on 5995867011
404 on 5995867012
404 on 5995867013
404 on 5995867014
5995867015 SUCCESS, entrynumber #12
404 on 5995867016
404 on 5995867017
5995867018 SUCCESS, entrynumber #13
5995867019 SUCCESS, entrynumber #14
404 on 5995867020
404 on 5995867021
5995867022 SUCCESS, entrynumber #15
5995867023 SUCCESS, entrynumber #16
404 on 5995867024
5995867025 SUCCESS, entrynumber #17
5995867026 SUCCESS, entrynumber #18
404 on 5995867027
404 on 5995867028
404 on 5995867029
5995867030 SUCCESS, entrynumber #19
5995867031 SUCCESS, entrynumber #20
404 on 5995867032
404 on 5995867033
404 on 5995867034
5995867035 SUCCESS, entrynumber #21
404 on 5995867036
5995867037 SUCCESS, entrynumber #22
404 on 5995867038
5995867039 SUCCESS, entrynumber #23
5995867040 SUCCESS, entrynumber #24
5995867041 SUCCESS, entrynumber #25
404 on 5995867042
404 on 5995867043
404 on 5995867044
5995867045 SUCCESS, entrynumber #26
5995867046 SUCCESS, entrynumber #27
5995867047 SUCCESS, entrynumber #28
5995867048 SUCCESS, entrynumber #29
5995867049 SUCCESS, entrynumber #30
5995867050 SUCCESS, entrynumber #31
404 on 5995867051
404 on 5995867052
404 on 5995867053
404 on 5995867054
5995867055 SUCCESS, entrynumber #32
5995867056 SUCCESS, entrynumber #33
5995867057 SUCCESS, entrynumber #34
5995867058 SUCCESS, entrynumber #35
404 on 5995867059
404 on 5995867060
404 on 5995867061
404 on 5995867062
5995867063 SUCCESS, entrynumber #36
5995867064 SUCCESS, entrynumber #37
5995867065 SUCCESS, entrynumber #38
404 on 5995867066
404 on 5995867067
404 on 5995867068
404 on 5995867069
5995867070 SUCCESS, entrynumber #39
5995867071 SUCCESS, entrynumber #40
404 on 5995867072
404 on 5995867073
404 on 5995867074
5995867075 SUCCESS, entrynumber #41
5995867076 SUCCESS, entrynumber #42
5995867077 SUCCESS, entrynumber #43
5995867078 SUCCESS, entrynumber #44
404 on 5995867079
404 on 5995867080
5995867081 SUCCESS, entrynumber #45
5995867082 SUCCESS, entrynumber #46
5995867083 SUCCESS, entrynumber #47
api cost full : infinite loop start
loop location :  5995867084
try 10 second wait time
429
try 10 second wait time
429
try 10 second wait time
429
try 10 second wait time
429
try 10 second wait time
404
```

Then the code runs without any additional output indefinitely, leading me to reason a loop has gone awry somewhere. What do you suppose is happening?

Comment: Do you know what HTTP 429 is telling you? Looks like there are constraints, even with an API Key, on the rate at which you're permitted to make requests. See this documentation:- https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/portal

Comment: @Stuart, HTTP 429 is a normal code since Riot limits requests to 100 requests every 2 minutes. I used the time.sleep (10) function to wait out the cooldown on the limiter.

Comment: Have you considered using the retry mechanism available within *requests* ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.